# Very simple javascript won't fire

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to write the world's simplest AJAX script just to test a PHP round trip. I must be losing my mind because I'm not even getting the "here" to come out of this thing. Instead, all I get is `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` which looks like a Chrome bug that should have nothing to do with this. Anyone see what I am too dense to see? Thanks.

EDIT: Even if I comment out everything after `console.log("here")` all the way through `return false`, I still don't get the simple console output "here" to appear. Aaugh!

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Tester</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function testPHP() {

            var first = "vic";
            var second = "tory";

            console.log("here");

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    console.log(response);
                }
            }

            var content =   "first="    +encodeURIComponent(id)+
                            "&second="  +encodeURIComponent(second);

            xmlhttp.open("POST","phpTest.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(content);

            return false;
        }

    </script>

    <div>

        <button type="submit" onClick="testPHP()">Test PHP</button>          

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try dropping the `return false;` line on the click function.

Comment: I get `here` to print and then the id undefined, are you still not seeing `here`?

Comment: @usr55410 : Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Ack! I was looking in the wrong place. That weird Chrome warning took me to a different area of the console, and I didn't notice. Thanks to everybody for pointing out my other issues, though. Sorry to have bothered you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retry with:

```
<button type="button" onClick="testPHP()">Test PHP</button>
```

Also `id` is undefined maybe you want to use `first`:

```
var content = "first=" + encodeURIComponent(first) + "&second="  + encodeURIComponent(second);
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the button type and the argument. Doesn't seem to be the problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `undefined` message .. that is because you don't have any variable called `id`

Replace

```
var content =   "first="    +encodeURIComponent(id)+
```

with

```
var content =   "first="    +encodeURIComponent(first)+
                                             ----^ // Replace the id with this first
```

Comment: Good catch. Same problem, though. Thanks for pointing that out!